# Как поменять цвет активных фигурных и обычных скобок?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Использую тёмную тему MSVS2015. При активации скобок (когда ты внутри) они окрашиваются черным на черном фоне - ужасно неудобно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это обычное состояние.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А это при окрашивании. Не могу найти нужный пункт в настройках :(

Answer (score 1):

Ниже ссылка на полное руководство. Вот коротко то, что вам из него надо:

- в строке меню выберите **Сервис** > **Параметры**
- в разделе **Среда** выберите категорию **Шрифты и цвета**
- в поле **Показать параметры для** выбрать значение **Текстовый редактор**. Тут список элементов для которых можно настроить цвет текста.

[Практическое руководство. Персонализация интегрированной среды разработки и редактора Visual Studio](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/ide/quickstart-personalize-the-ide?view=vs-2019&viewFallbackFrom=vs-2015)